# How to handle huge number of checkboxes in javafx (fxml)

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to develop a fxml window where are huge number of check boxes. I know i can handle those check boxes by fx:id for each check boxes separately. Is there any way to handle those check boxes easily? Here is a snapshot of my fxml window created using Gluon Scene Builder

FXML Scene containing multiple checkboxes:

[image]

Comment: If you have such high number of checkboxes, I would recommend to not use FXML.

Comment: Then what should I use & how?

Comment: You could generate all the CheckBox using a simple loop in Java code

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. @ItachiUchiha

Comment: You can also use a `TableView` with a `CheckBoxCell` for each cell, then they are handled by the `TableView`.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha is right. You can add a Listener to each other witch get Checkbox Object... or bind its in loop.

Comment: `Map<String ,CheckBox> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            String s = String.valueOf(i);
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.setId(s);
            cb.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, e->
                System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            );
            map.put(s,cb);
        }`

Comment: You can also consider creating a [custom component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) for the label with the number and the three checkboxes. Then use a loop in your main controller to create the 31 instances of it.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I used TableView with CheckBoxCell as suggested by @Sunflame